# Notification to the the person

Tags: solspace-freeform, notification

Hej !

Free Form

- I know how make the notification, but how do I do it when I wanna send to the person who has wrote the from and I like to send.

like this
Dear {first_name} {last_name}.

Thank you for the email ({subject}).

We take the time to read it and then to connect you as soon as possible.

Best Regards

the admin notification goes okey

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure a Notification for the form and the template tags.

See: http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#notify_user

**Form Settings:**
[image: Freeform module Form Settings]

**Template Tags:**
[image: Freeform User Notifications docs]